# Automating CEF desktop client with EdgeDriver - Error : unrecognized MSEdge version: Chrome/92.0.4515.107'

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am running a CEF based desktop application on a remote debugging port using command prompt as below -

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\<FolderName>\<ApplicationName>.exe" --remote-debugging-port=5553`

The application is getting launched and I am able to inspect the dev tools on 'localhost:5553'.
I am trying to connect this application with the MS Edge driver using C#. Below is my code -

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("webdriver.edge.driver", @"C:\Users\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
EdgeOptions eo = new EdgeOptions();
eo.AddArguments("UseChromium ", "true");
eo.UseWebView = true;
eo.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\";
eo.DebuggerAddress = "127.0.0.1:5553";
WebDriver d = new EdgeDriver(eo);
```

While executing code line 'WebDriver d = new EdgeDriver(eo);', i am receiving error **"OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: 'unknown error: cannot connect to msedge at 127.0.0.1:5553
from unknown error: unrecognized MSEdge version: Chrome/92.0.4515.107'"**

MS Edge Browser version  = 95.0.1020.30 (Official build) (64-bit)

Microsoft Web Driver Version = 95.0.997.1

I also have Chrome browser installed on my system with version 95.0.4638.54 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: 95_Win_54).
I am not sure how the edge driver is referring to Chrome/92.0.4515.107, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's the version of CEF? Reference link: [CEF Release Branches](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.md#markdown-header-legacy-release-branches-unsupported).

Why you use EdgeDriver to automate CEF-based application? According to the [official doc](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md), I suggest that you use corresponding version of ChromeDriver to make the automation.